# how to debug jni file in android eclipse with ndk-r8d

Tags: android-ndk

Android 2.3,ndk 8 I have search  so many articles on google but it does not give any result    Please help me by telling simple step for debug native code JNI/c++ application in eclipse with ndk r8d

Answer (score 0):

ASAIK there is draw back that you can`t debug the JNI part of Android Project 
yes you can do 1 thing that is 
place Android Debug in JNI Class Wher you want the Response

```
 __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "TRACKERS", "%s", Str);
```

Wtih the following Include

```
#include <android/log.h>
```

Comment: I want use breakpoint in c++ code is there any process work with new version of ndk-r8d